# php Hide variables passed in header

Tags: php, header

First of all: I found a lot of similar questions but can't get what im looking for (maybe because i'm not good at english)

Second: I would like to know if its possible to do what I need with PHP (not JS/AJAX/anything)

Ok, hands on it:

I have the usual login form, when clicking on "submit" it calls a php function to make the sql query.

I want to redirect to the login page and print a message in the form saying the user/pass is not correct.

- Code

  ```
      $login = login($conn);

      $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($login); 

      if ($rowcount == 0)
          {
              header('Location:login.php?msg='.urlencode('<p style="color:red" align="center">Usuario o password incorrecto</p>'));
  ```

That code its working, found it here while lurking.

After that, in the form I just made an echo to $_GET['msg'] and worked perfectly.

BUT!!!! the URL appears like:

```
myurl/login.php?msg=<p+style%3D"color%3Ared"+align%3D"center">Usuario+o+password+incorrecto<%2Fp>
```

And its awful!

Is there any way to pass it some kind of hidden?

Comment: why do u need to pass style in url? you can set style (css) when you display error message

Comment: I know, I was trying different  things to mak it work, the only one it worked was passing that string, im not yet working on the css.

Edit... damm enter

But besides the "style" what i would like to not show is all that because it looks awful, 

"p+style%3D"color%3Ared"+align%3D"center">Usuario+o+password+incorrecto<%2Fp>"

Would like to change that with a variable or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use session: use session_start() at top:

```
if ($rowcount == 0)
    {
        header('Location:login.php');
        $_SESSION['msg'] = urlencode('<p style="color:red" align="center">Usuario o password incorrecto</p>');
    }
```

Then call your session variable on your page "login.php".

Comment: Hi rhonexiled. I did that but its not being shown: http://prntscr.com/go6lcj I draw a line where the text should appear.

Comment: in login.php add "session_start();" Then call your variable: "echo $_SESSION['msg'];" when you want it to display.

Comment: Awesome, its working right now, but I still need to do a bit of a twist.

The SESSION keeps charged if i press F5, so i need a condition to post it, the problem is, any variable used is being retrieved from cache. I'm working on making a non-cacé page, but is not working yet. BTW, Thanks pall!